# How can I change a style via code that is stored in a resource dictionary in App.xaml on the fly?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am trying to have the ability for several core colors throughout the app to be changeable on the fly by the user. My current idea is to have a single SolidColorBrush that is my "theme color" and then to reference that throughout my main styles.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ReflectiveColor1" Color="#FF0E777B"></SolidColorBrush>
```

This snippet is stored in a resourcedictionary that is reference in my App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="DictionaryAlienwareTheme.xaml">
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

When I try and access the color in my App.cs I get an error

```
 Application.Current.Resources["ReflectiveColor1"] = Colors.Black;
```

Error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'No installed components were 
detected.
Local values are not allowed in resource dictionary with Source set
```

Is there anyway to make this work? I'm assuming this error is because it doesn't want us to modify styles stored there, but I don't know the workaround.

Comment: The color assignment is also wrong. You are trying to assign a Color to what was a SolidColorBrush before. It should probably be `((SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["ReflectiveColor1"]).Color = Colors.Black;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in your `App.xaml` if you want to reference the `DictionaryAlienwareTheme.xaml` you defined by yourself you need to merge the dictionaries to current app as @AVK said. More details please reference "Merged resource dictionaries" section of [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references).

Secondly, after you use the merged resource, if you want to update the theme resource code behind you may need to use `Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries` to visit the merged dictionaries instead of `Application.Current.Resources`. For example,

```
public MainPage()
{
   this.InitializeComponent(); 
   var mergedDict = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.FirstOrDefault();
   ((SolidColorBrush)mergedDict["ReflectiveColor1"]).Color = Colors.Red;
}
```

By the way, as above code snippet showed, `ReflectiveColor1` is `SolidColorBrush` you cannot set color directly.

Comment: I have done exactly what you have asked for, still getting the error - "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'No installed components were detected.

Local values are not allowed in resource dictionary with Source set [Line: 0 Position: 0]'"

Answer (score 1):

Application will not be able to find the Resource `ReflectiveColor1` until you merge all resource dictionaries together.

Change your `App.xaml` to Merge the dictionaries. Like below.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="DictionaryAlienwareTheme.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then you should be able to access the Resource in the same way that you were doing before.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work fully although it's closer. In the other XAML how would you reference the ReflectiveColor1? I've tried Binding and ThemeResource but they don't seem to update to the color chosen in the code.